# Pointer and declaration difficulty

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here's a piece of my code that I divided. I basically need to create 3 functions:

1. Fill array with random numbers
2. Print array on the screen
3. *Is not included in this piece.*

My problem is that I get the

**C2664 error:cannot convert parameter 1 from int[6][6] to int(*)[].**

And I cant figure what's wrong with my code. I would also like to check if how I wrote my pointers to fill and print the array is correct.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
const int AS = 6;
void FillingRandomly(int *);
void printing(int *);

int c;

int main()    
{
    int funny = 0;
    int timpa = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int Array[AS][AS];
    srand(time(0));    

    FillingRandomly(Array);     

    cout << "The unsorted array is" << endl << endl;    
    printing(Array);    

    cout << "The sorted array is" << endl << endl;

    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;    
}

void FillingRandomly(int *Array) {
    *Array = rand()%87 +12;
    *Array ++;
}



void printing(int *ArrayPtr) {
    int counter = 0;
    while(*ArrayPtr<AS*AS) {
    cout<<*ArrayPtr;
    *ArrayPtr++;

    if (*ArrayPtr%AS == 0)
        cout << endl << endl;
    }   
}
```

Comment: A common mistake when trying to handle multi-dimensional arrays. My traditional advice is to stick with single-dimensional arrays, playing with indexes to fake multiple dimensions if you need them. I also suggest fixing your indentation because, right now, it's god-awful. :)

Comment: Array is commonly a keyword in c++, meaning it is not allowed to be used. int *Array is not the same as Array[6][6]. What you could be looking into is how to pass an array into a function a go from there. FillingRandomly will only do its thing once, then increase what it is pointing at and jumping out. What you want to do is go through the whole array and give random values. In this case I recommend two for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use pointers to `int`, because you want to pass an array, not a pointer, to your functions.

In addition, pass it by reference. To do this, change the declarations for your functions:

```
void FillingRandomly(int (&Array)[AS][AS]);
void printing(const int (&Array)[AS][AS]);
```

(the declaration is different for `printing` because it doesn't need to change the array)

The definition must be written in the same manner:

```
void FillingRandomly(int (&Array)[AS][AS])
{
    ...
}
```

Note also that in C++ arrays are sometimes (or most always - depends on whom you ask) represented by the standard-library classes, like `std::vector` or `std::array`. I'll not show the code for using them to keep my answer focused.